# Inline Frame Form Submission Redirect to Parent

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect, hyperlink

I have an IFRAME that displays a search form.  Picture:

```
<IFRAME 
SRC="<IFRAME 
SRC="https://www.google.com"
HEIGHT="410"
WIDTH="174">
</IFRAME>
```

I am wondering if there is a way to make it so that when someone types in text and hits "enter" the parent page redirects to the page that the form submission would take you to...  (so in this example you would be taken to the search result).

I know how to redirect normal links by giving them the trait: `_parent`  But I don't know how to make this work with a form.

Comment: just to be clear, are you asking so that, you submit a form in the child iframe, and it causes the iframe to go to the submitted page?

Comment: also  you can add the `target="_parent"` trait to a form

Comment: No, I want to submit the form in the child and have it redirect the parent to the form result.

I can't add anything to the form, because I don't own it.  Its on another website.